# Why does "echo $DISPLAY" output ":0.0" on my secondary monitor

Tags: xorg, display, environment-variables

I know that `DISPLAY` is organized as

```
host:display.screen
```

However, `echo $DISPLAY` outputs :0.0 on both my laptop monitor as well as on my secondary monitor connected to the computer via VGA. So, while I have two screens, the "screen" variable still outputs 0. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The two physical displays are joined into a single logical display. Notice how a window can be dragged so it's half on one monitor and half on another.

### Follow-up to OP comment

Almost everyone sees ":0.0". the exception are people with two video cards who will see ":0.0" for the first video card and ":0.1" for the second video card.

Although I only have two monitors of 1920x1080 pixels built-in and 1920x1080 pixels HDMI TV my Intel Graphics card supports a region of 32 KB x 32KB pixels (there abouts) so there is lots of "virtual space" for not only these two monitors but many more.

I don't feel I'm answering your question properly because I don't fully understand the significance of your question and comments. Are you curious how an application knows which pixels in virtual space to draw a window on when there are two or more monitors? You will notice when a given monitor window has focus and you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the `Terminal` it opens on the top left of that monitor and not the other. Is something like this the basis of your query?

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks, I figured that's what "display" stands for, but what about "screen" then? Or are you referring to "screen"? If so, what is meant by "display", then?

Comment: 8m on my phone so long answers are difficult now aorry

Comment: @AlphaOmega Sorry for delay. I updated the answer to hopefully answer your question, or perhaps let you clarify your comments so I can understand better.

Comment: Thanks again! Would you mind explaining the difference between "display" and "screen", i.e. between the first 0 and the second 0 in :0.0? Judging from your response, two video cards still output to the same "display", but to two different "screens". Is that right?

Comment: I'd love to but I'm on my phone right now. It'll have to wait until tonight when I can use the computer.